# Проблема с подключение к сайту Instagram

Tags: python, requests, instagram

Я пробовал подключаться к сайту Инстаграм через requests, но всегда выскакивала огромная ошибка. Так как его заблокировали на территории РФ, нужно ли включать VPN в браузере или на самом ПК?
p.s Пробовал включать vpn в браузере,но все равно была ошибка

Comment: Нужно. Включайте

Comment: Ну да, в РФ без VPN не будет соединяться. А где включать зависит от того, через что ваш скрипт работает.